# get_template_part function and add images

Tags: php, functions, get-template-part

Added this function in any page:

```
get_template_part('recent', 'posts');
```

And:

```
if(have_posts()){
while(have_posts()){ the_post(); ?>
    <div class="site-content clearfix"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php }
}
```

It's working, show 5 blog post on my page. But it's have only title and publish date. I want add thumbnail images on this post.

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? So far you're showing us a template part and my answer would be: Go, read up in Codex about template tags and thumbnails/featured images.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the post thumbnail by using [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail):

```
 echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'thumbnail' );
```

Comment: Or just use `the_post_thumbnail()` which is almost the same thing, but it echoes the thumbnail HTML code instead of returning it.